# algorithm to find a point among n points in plane to minimize the sum of distances

Tags: algorithm

I have an algorithm problem here. It is different from the normal [Fermat Point problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point).

Given a set of `n` points in the plane, I need to find which one can minimize the sum of distances to the rest of `n-1` points.

Is there any algorithm you know of run less than O(n^2)?

Thank you.

Comment: You want the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median

Comment: Do you require the algorithm to work with just Euclidian distance or any kind of distance ?

Comment: @ScottHunter I think he wants the closest point to the geometric median (which shouldn't be much harder to find) but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Josay: idealy for any `distance`, but Euclidian one is fine.

Comment: @ScottHunter: I said the two problems are different. Here, I am requiring the target point is one of the given points.

Comment: @Josay: is there any proof for what you said to be true? i.e., the point closest to the geometric median is the target point?

Comment: @littleEinstein I don't have any proof and I don't even know if it's true but I  couldn't find any couter-examples.

Comment: I believe you should post this on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to assume median is close to the mean and for a subset of points close to the mean exhaustively calculate sum of distances. You can choose klog(n) points closest to the mean, where k is an arbitrarily chosen constant (complexity nlog(n)).

Another possible solution is Delaunay Triangulation. This triangulation is possible in O(nlogn) time. The triangulation results in a graph with one vertex for each point and edges to satisfy delauney triangulation.
Once you have the triangulation, you can start at any point and compare sum-of-distances of that point to its neighbors and keep moving iteratively. You can stop when the current point has the minimum sum-of-distance compared to its neighbors. Intuitively, this will halt at the global optimal point.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. What do you mean exactly "for a subset of points close to the mean"? How do you define "close" here. Also in the "Delaunay Triangulation" thought, how to "keep moving iteratively"? How to tell the stopping criterion?

Answer (score 1):

I think the underlying assumption here is that you have a dataset of points which you can easily bound, as many algorithms which would be "good enough" in practice may not be rigorous enough for theory and/or may not scale well for arbitrarily large solutions.

A very simple solution which is probably "good enough" is to sort the coordinates on the Y ordinate, then do a stable sort on the X ordinate.

Take the rectangle defined by the min(X,Y) and max(X,Y) values, complexity O(1) as the values will be at known locations in the sorted dataset.

Now, working from the center of your sorted dataset, find coordinate values as close as possible to {Xctr = Xmin + (Xmax - Xmin) / 2, Yctr = Ymin + (Ymax - Ymin) / 2} -- complexity O(N) bounded by your minimization criteria, distance being the familiar radius from {Xctr,Yctr}.

The worst case complexity would be comparing your centroid to every other point, but once you get away from the middle points you will not be improving the global optimal and should terminate the search.